# Solving words that when print match but when you use .contain does not match

Tags: flutter

A common issue many of the developers might face while building an app with localization (especially when it involves Arabic or an RTL-supported language), is that the search would not result as expected. An example of the issue is:

```
  print(listOfName.contains(InputName))); //prints false
```

To overcome this issue, I tried comparing the encoded search strings (in both languages) and encoded result strings then only realized that somehow some special characters had been added. For my instance, the characters were RTL[226, 128, 143] and LTR[226, 128, 142]. Before I actually encoded the strings, both search and result were identical or equals to the same. After knowing the extra added characters, I did the following:

```
  var  InputNameEncode = InputName.encode
  var rightToLeftMark = utf8.decode([226, 128, 143]);
  var leftToRightMark = utf8.decode([226, 128, 142]);

  InputNameEncode = InputNameEncode.replaceAll(rightToLeftMark, "");
  InputNameEncode = InputNameEncode.replaceAll(leftToRightMark, "");
  inputName = InputNameEncode.decode
  print(listOfName.contains(InputName))); //prints true
```

As mentioned earlier, in my case the extra characters were RTL and LTR. In your case, you may find something entirely different.

You can know what each encoded set of characters represents on this page: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=dec

Flutter Version: 1.22.6

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: I wasn't sure how to write it as a blog so i posted it as a question